# Difference between subject coordinator and head of subject?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I have a question about the titles "subject coordinator" and "head of subject" respectively. I have looked at a whole bunch of different contexts where these two are used, but I've failed to find a pattern as to how they're used – both seem to appear in university as well as school contexts, and both seem to be used in BrE as well as in AmE  – so now I'm wondering whether they are in fact true synonyms, or if there is a difference between them.

Comment: I suspect that it depends entirely on what the individual institution chooses to call the role; there is no pattern or difference between them. I note that one job description for a 'coordinator' also calls them a 'subject leader'.

Comment: @KateBunting Right, as I thought then – I just wanted to make sure :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just different terms, that may imply a different attitude at the school

A "head" is a leader - someone who gives orders.

A "coordinator" is someone who gets a team working together, who listens and negotiates.

Saying "subject coordinator" means that the culture of the school is based on teamwork and corporation and not leaders and followers.